useSession always returns empty user object after authentication
I am trying to implement Auth.js in my Next.js project and I managed to make the login work but when I try to access the user data from the session the user object is always empty even tho the session says authenticated and has an expiration date.
I mainly followed the official docs to set it up. Here is the code I have in auth.ts:
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
        credentials: {
          email: {},
          password: {},
        },
        authorize: async (credentials) => {
          let data = {
            email: credentials.email as string,
            password: credentials.password as string,
          }

          const user = await AuthService.login(data)

          console.log('the user', user)
   
          return user
        },
    }),
  ],
})

When I perform a login, it all works fine and the user variable shows with all the user data in the console.log I have there. I made an AuthProvider component where I import the auth method of the configuration above to get the session data:
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { auth } from "@/lib/auth";

export interface Props {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default async function AuthProvider({ children }: Props) {
    const session = await auth();

    return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
            {children}
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}

I use the component to wrap the children of my main layout.tsx file like so:
export default async function RootLayout({
  return (
      <AuthProvider>
        {children}
      </AuthProvider>
  );
}

All well and good, now here is where I run into an issue, I have a UserPanel component where I want to show the info from the session. I have it setup like this:
 'use client'    
 export default function UserPanel() {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();

    console.log('the session', session, status);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{session.user.name}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

When I log in successfully the the info I get from useSession() returns and empty user object:
{
    "user": {},
    "expires": "2024-09-09T03:21:18.233Z"
}

It shows an expiration date and the status says authenticated. But none of the user data that my API returns is available.
How do I get the user data with useSession? Thanks in advance.

You need to add the session callback. and attach the necessary details that need to displayed on the client side session.
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        let data = {
          email: credentials.email,
          password: credentials.password,
        };

        const user = await AuthService.login(data);

        console.log('the user', user);

        return user || null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // Attach the user information to the session
      session.user = token.user;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
});

for adding additional paramerts to the user object create a new file called next-auth.d.ts
import { DefaultSession, DefaultUser } from 'next-auth';
import { JWT, DefaultJWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: string;
      email: string;
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
      isAdmin: boolean;
    } & DefaultSession['user'];
  }

  interface User extends DefaultUser {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
  }
}

declare module 'next-auth/jwt' {
  interface JWT extends DefaultJWT {
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
  }
}

And extend the current user, provided by default from your necessary parameters.

Thanks for your response, appreciate it. I am using TypeScript and I am trying it like you wrote but session.user is giving me the error Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'AdapterUser & User'. Do you know how this could be avoided?

Got it to work by using session.user = token.user as any, not sure it is the best way to go about it but it did return the user info as expected. Thanks again for the help!

edited the question for your answer
